# How do I render Crystal Report from HANA DB

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, hana

I have a routine that I've been using for years with Microsoft SQL, but now it needs to work with HANA DB. I've rewritten the code lots of times with any exapmple that I can find, but I still get a Engine.InternalException "Failed to open the connection". Crystal report designer on the same maachine is able to open the report. Here's my code:

```
Public Sub SaveCrystalReport(ByVal RptFilename As String, ByVal ReportParameters As Hashtable, SaveAsPDFFileName As String)
    Trace.TraceInformation("PrintCrystalReport(): " & RptFilename)

    Using cdoc As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
        Trace.TraceInformation("Loading report: " & RptFilename)
        cdoc.Load(RptFilename)

        For Each paramKey As CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterField In cdoc.ParameterFields
            Trace.TraceInformation("Report has parameter: " & paramKey.Name)

            If ReportParameters.ContainsKey(paramKey.Name) Then
                Trace.TraceInformation("Print request has parameter " & paramKey.Name & ", setting it.")
                Try
                    Dim rptparam As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ParameterFieldDefinition = cdoc.DataDefinition.ParameterFields.Item(paramKey.Name)
                    If rptparam IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not rptparam.IsLinked Then
                        cdoc.SetParameterValue(paramKey.Name, ReportParameters.Item(paramKey.Name))
                    End If
                Catch pex As Exception
                    Trace.TraceError("Failed to set parameter in crystal report: " & paramKey.Name & vbCrLf & pex.ToString)
                End Try
            End If
        Next

        Dim ci As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo

        ci.AllowCustomConnection = True

        ci.UserID = CompanySQLUser
        ci.Password = CompanySQLPass
        ci.ServerName = CompanySQLServer
        ci.DatabaseName = CompanyDatabase

        ci.LogonProperties.Clear()
        ci.LogonProperties.Add(New NameValuePair2("ConnectionString", ci.ServerName))
        ci.LogonProperties.Add(New NameValuePair2("UseDSNProperties", False))

        'cdoc.SetDatabaseLogon(CompanySQLUser, CompanySQLPass, CompanySQLServer, CompanyDatabase)
        cdoc.SetDatabaseLogon(CompanySQLUser, CompanySQLPass)

        For Each tbl As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In cdoc.Database.Tables

            Dim logon As CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo = tbl.LogOnInfo
            logon.ConnectionInfo = ci
            tbl.ApplyLogOnInfo(logon)
        Next

        cdoc.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, SaveAsPDFFileName)
    End Using
End Sub
```

I am passing a DBName, username and Password, but for the server I am passing an ODBC connection string of the form "DRIVER={B1CRHPROXY};SERVERNODE=...;DATABASE=..." and my Database setting matches the one in my connection string. Internally, the report is using ConnectionInfoType CRQE, which I believe is correct for ODBC style connections.

I also tried this without applying any connection info except for username and password, which I would have presumed would render reports from the database encapsulated in the report file, but that doesn't work either.

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here - has naaybody been able to render Crystal via the API when backed by a HANA DB?

Thanks

Comment: If you can retrieve the data and store it in a dataset/datatable, the you can use the datatable as crystalreport's datasource. Like crReport.SetDataSource(your_datatable). In your report design, use an XSD to get the structure of your data.

Comment: The data tables are quite large, and I don't want to replicate the report queries in my application. I saw that though and it looks interesting.